# Csv files written by opencsv cannot be found on pc

Tags: android, opencsv, hidden-files

I am writing a simple application which export csv files from database.
The csv files can be found by using android application(e.g. file manager).
However, when I connect the device to pc, those csv files were not found.

Is there any setting for the access right of the csv generated by opencsv?
Or any way to view those generated csv files in pc?

Thank you.

Comment: Does your device have an SD card?  If so, what happens if you plug your card into a USB card reader, then plug the reader into the PC?  If you do that, neither android nor your device will be involved.  If your CSV files aren't on your card, then they should be on your device's filesystem.  If that's the case, I don't know how to help you, but maybe a card reader will solve your problem.

Comment: Hi michael, I am using Nexus 5 and there was no SD card. So, I can read the csv files through the mobile only?